# Convert 32 bit exe to 64 bit exe on Windows 7 64 bit machine

Tags: c#, x86, 64-bit, com-interop

Developed an 32 bit Visual Basic dll.
dll written only 1 method **GetSum** having two integer parameteres

Now using late binding load an dll in Winform 32 bit application.
pass two integer values show the sum in label.
the sum shows correct.

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     object[] args = new object[] { "89", "2" };
     Type comObjectType = Type.GetTypeFromProgID("Project1.Class1", true);
     object comObject = Activator.CreateInstance(comObjectType);
     Type acctualObjectType = comObject.GetType();
     object result = acctualObjectType.InvokeMember("GetSum", System.Reflection.BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, comObject, args);
     label1.Text = result.ToString();
}
```

My problem is when i run the winfrom exe on windows 7 64 bit machine.
in task manager processes section shows like "WindowsFormsApplication.exe *32"

Means my winfrom exe is running as 32 bit mode on 64 bit machine.
What should i do to run my 32 bit exe on 64 bit machine to run as 64 bit exe.

Dont want *32 append to exe in task manager processes section.

Comment: Have you set the Platform Target to `AnyCPU` and turned off `Prefer 32-bit`?

Comment: when i set platform to any cpu then exe corrcltly works on 32 bit machine but it crashes in 64 bit machine giving an error class not registered..System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x80040154): Retrieving the COM class factory for component with CLSID {0AAB73EC-446B-4142-B758-9637D4CA8E18} failed due to the following error: 80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154 (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG)).

Comment: Matthew where is tab for Prefer 32-bit

Comment: It's next to the "AnyCPU" setting, but it's only there for VS2012. Are you using VS2010 by any chance?

Comment: Matthew  i am using vs2010

Comment: Ok so what happens if you set the Platform Target to `x64`?

Comment: when i set platform to any cpu then exe works correctly on 32 bit machine but it crash on 64 bit machine

Comment: Then I guess your COM library that you're using doesn't support 64 bits, so you will have to stick with 32 bits.

Comment: matthew Should i register 32 bit COM library as 64 bit on 64 bit machine

Comment: I should think it will only work in 32 bits. But surely this is no problem? If you're not running out of memory, there's no need for 64 bits (unless you *must* use 64 bits for compatibility with some other DLL or COM library)

Comment: Matthew is there anyway.

Answer (score 0):

First: for creating the dll, are you using Visual Basic .NET or legacy Visual Basic 6?

If you are using VB6, you won't be able to create a 64bit dll. If you are using VB.NET, compile your dll to 64bit.

And remember, if your VB dll is a 32bit dll, you won't be able to use it from a 64bit application.

Comment: i cant do anything on dll level ...client gives me 32 bit dll always

Comment: @Nikhil: well, you have no option. You must create 32bit apps.

Comment: AFAIK, it's impossible to comunicate a 64bit app with a 32bit dll.